# Stuck at login loop while tty and recovery mode terminal works fine

Tags: shell, login, tty

I am having linux mint 18. I accidentally removed `/bin/bash`. So just after removing it I changed the default shell of the user from terminal (from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/sh` and `/bin/sh` links to `dash`) in `/etc/passwd`. Now After reboot I am stuck in login loop. After typing credential get blank screen for 10 seconds again get same login screen. Also `tty1 tty2...` are not working. As I enter my credential they disappears and again get same thing on these terminals.

***problem 2***

When I enter in recovery mode I am getting the same login screen as normal user. I am not getting recovery mode options. It just brings me to login screen.

***edit 1***

I pressed e at the grub menu and I added `rw init=/bin/dash` at the end of line where linux /boot/vmlinuz.... is written.

Output of `ls -l /etc/passwd` is `rw-r--r-- root root`

If I do `cat /etc/passwd` users entry is

```
user:x:1000:1000:user,,,:/home/user:/bin/dash
```

`ls -l /bin/dash` shows it doesn't point to `/bin/bash`. As one answer said to check it.

***edit 2***

I downloaded bash package in my windows system, copied to external hard disk and then copied it from hard disk to linux system. Compiled and installed it. Copied executable to `/bin/bash`.

Now used `chsh -s /bin/bash user`

Now I can go into recovery mode it works fine.I can use `tty1..` they also work fine.I can switch to user using `su user` in `tty1` and it works fine. If I do `echo $SHELL` it says `/bin/bash`, but still can't go into graphical environment.Neither guest nor user can log into graphical system.User can use terminal easily it works there but can't use graphical environment.

Comment: How did you change /bin/bash to /bin/sh? I guess you used a live CD. I wish what we are trying to understand was clearer. If I read correctly, we are trying to understand how it comes that `/bin/sh` is not work. Can you describe the login loop a bit more? Do you get a message before the prompt comes back? Maybe the screen is cleared so you can't read anything ?

Comment: At that time it was working fine I just changed through nano in terminal. I didn't use any live CD. No message just enter password get blank screen for 10 seconds then again same screen.

Comment: You should probably use a live CD to make sure everything is fine in your /etc/passwd, and the permissions are set correctly (`-rw-r--r--`, or 644). If you can ssh to your machine, you probably can run commands one by one (unsure) / scp bash.

Comment: (1) If console login doesn’t work, ssh probably won’t either.  (2) Booting with a live CD is a pretty good idea, but if `init=/bin/dash` works, that’s good too.  Use whichever you find more appropriate or convenient.  (3) Buddika suggested that there might be a problem with `/bin/dash`.  It’s good to check multiple ways (e.g., with `ls -l`), but the fact that you got a shell with `init=/bin/dash` really demonstrated that `dash` works.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) You might want to make a copy of `/etc/passwd`, (a) as a backup (in case you make things worse), and (b) so you can examine it at your leisure later.  (5) Fixing `/etc/passwd` with `usermod` or `chsh` is probably a good idea.  (6) Do an octal or hex dump of `/etc/passwd` and see whether you typed a space after ``/bin/dash``.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us informed.  But I believe that your question title is misleading now; you can’t login ***to the graphic console**,* but tty (and recovery mode terminal) work fine.  And I believe that you’ve reached a point where you should accept [Buddika’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/454032/80216#454108) and ask a new question (linking to this one for reference).  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. Did you ever identify the problem with `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I wanted to add this as a comment but still not allowed to comment*

1. Make sure there are no formatting errors in /etc/passwd.
2. Hope "dash" does not link back to /bin/bash. :D
3. Instead of editing /etc/passwd directly try changing the shell of the user using `usermod` command.
4. If the problem still exists, your best option is to reinstall bash.
5. If it still won't work, try Mathieu CAROFF's option.

Comment: It's actually great that you've posted an answer. The site's features kick in and make it much easier to create a useful repository of questions and answers.